# How to make SSIS package look like DTS

Tags: ssis, dts

I was wanting to know if there was a way to run an SSIS package, besides in the IDE to monitor the progress by step.

To explain this a little better when you run a DTS package that has say 5 steps in it,the process shows you each step, which step it is currently running, which ones have fail/sucsess and so on.

Is there a way to do this with a SSIS package.

I tried running a SQL job that did 2 SSIS packages and 2 T-SQL statements but, the job just showed the job running and no details about what it was doing or what step it was on and so on.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide on this topic.

Robin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out Logging? Package logging should be able to give you a whole lot of information about the package such as the component run time, success/failure and etc. If you want to view it on the GUI side then I am afraid, you will have to run it in BIDS which is not optimal when you think about production environment.